# synthetic division/long division divisor sign

Tags: polynomials

I know that if you are dividing by $x-3$ with long, then if you do it with synthetic division it's going to be positive 3 that gets used, the value used in synth. division is opposite. So if your determining if a number is a zero of a function, have say $3, 5, -2, f(one of those)$ or whatever, x +/- is the same sign as those and then whats used in synth opposites of those? so $x + 3, x + 5, x -2$ and then $-3 -5 +2$ for synth? Or is it the other way around? $x - 3, x - 5, x + 2$ and then the original signs for synthetic division?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following equation
$$(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)=0$$
When you do the synthetic division yo will need to use x=1,x=2 and x=3. Notice that those numbers give you a solution of the equation. Moreover you need
$$x-1=0$$ or $$x-2=0$$ or $$x-3=0$$
That is why you should use $x=1$, $x=2$, or $x=3$ in the synth division.